# How do I make the left menu out by clicking the actionbar Icon?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

I have tried using [Jeremy library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) with ActionBarSherlock.

Example on my xml, I have created an `ImageButton` which I put a "Settings" Image on the right corner of the `ActionBar`. So what I want is when the user slide the application to the right a settings menu will appear or when the user click on the "Settings" image the menu will come out. I am able to show the menu by sliding to the right but I can't do it when I click on the "Setting" image. How do I do that?.

I have an action bar custom xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >
      <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/BackImg"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:src="@drawable/abc" />
     <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/BtnSetting"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:src="@drawable/setting" 
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
     <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/BtnMenu"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:src="@drawable/menu" 
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
private void showActionBar() {
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.ab_custom, null);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled (false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
  }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    showActionBar();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_leftcontainer);
    SlidingMenu menu = getSlidingMenu();
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.setBehindOffset(200);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_menu_container, new LeftMenuFragment());
    ft.commit();
    menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_rightcontainer);
    menu.setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft1.add(R.id.fragment_menu_container1, new RightMenuFragment());
    ft1.commit();
 }
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.BtnMenu:

          if(menu.isMenuShowing()) 
          { menu.showContent(); } 
          else 
          {
              menu.showMenu();
              }
        return true;
    case R.id.BtnSetting:
          if(menu.isMenuShowing()) 
          { menu.showContent(); } 
          else 
          {
              menu.showMenu();
              }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My LeftMenuFragment

```
public class LeftMenuFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftmenu, container, false);
    }
}
```

So when I run my application I can slide it left and right for the menu to pop up but when I click the icons on the `ActionBar` the menu didn't pop up, can anyone teach me how do I pop the menu out by clicking on the icon and how do I hide the menu by clicking it again when the menu is out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this lib to create Sliding menu.https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

for Action bar home button click :

set supportActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`
 override the onMenuItemSelected method

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:

      (menu.isMenuShowing()) { menu.showContent(); } else { menu.showMenu(); }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes i did use the lib to create the sliding menu, the sliding menu works when sliding to the left but when i click on the "Menu" icon on the action bar it doesn't appears

Comment: u can code on menu click like if (menu.isMenuShowing()) {
    menu.showContent();
   } else {
    menu.showMenu();
   }

Comment: I am sorry i am kind of new to coding so if it's possible if you could give me a more detail explaination thanks :(

Comment: still not showing
 '@Override
 public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

     int itemId = item.getItemId();
     switch (itemId) {
     case R.id.BtnMenu:

       if(menu.isMenuShowing()) 
       { menu.showContent(); } 
       else { menu.showMenu(); }
     }

     return true;
 }'

Comment: Sorry for my poor english. Let me rephrase. Example on my xml, i have created an Image Button which I put a "Setting" Image on the right corner of the action bar. So what I want is when the user slide the application to the right a Setting Menu will appear or when the user click on the Image "Setting" the Menu will come out. I am able to show the menu by sliding to the right but I can't do it when I click on the "Setting" image. How do I do that?